# How to add a scroll to top button in AMP Email

Tags: amp-html, amp-email

Since javascript is not allowed inside AMP email, is there an alternate way to add a scroll to top in AMP emails?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not supported. There is a feature request related to this: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/27460.